# preparedstatement with multiple rows where some row values are not set

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a prepared statement like so

```
insert into mytable (id, name) values (?,?) , (?,?);
```

I am using multiple  rows per preparedStatement because i was seeing massive speed gains.

Now if i have an odd number of rows to enter then the `preparedStatement.executeBatch()` does not enter any rows in the DB. It does not throw any error.

here is how i insert the values

```
int count =0;
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    statement.setObject(1, id[i]);
    statement.setObject(2, name[i]);

    //second row
    if(i+1 != size) {
        statement.setObject(1, id[i+1]);
        statement.setObject(2, name[i+1]);
    }

    statement.addBatch();
    if (count % 200 == 0 && count >0) {
        statement.executeBatch();
    }
}
statement.executeBatch();
```

What can i do to make it work?

Comment: you can have several PreparedStatements, each one for a different set of inputs

Comment: @codeNinja: How is size calculated? Can you add more code that is executed before your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this automatically using the "rewriteBatchedStatements" option in the MySQL driver. You can write a single insert statement and execute it as a batch and the driver will rewrite it for you automatically to execute in as few round-trips as possible. c.f. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

With this solution, you do not have to use the multiple row form of INSERT.